# macOS - AVCaptureSession.stopRunning() crash

Tags: swift, macos, camera, crash, capture

I have the following code (I copied whole class because I don't really get what the problem is; the function with the problem is displayImage - last 4 lines of code or so):

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet var previewBox: NSView!
@IBOutlet var captureBox: NSImageView!

let cameraSession = AVCaptureSession()
let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) as AVCaptureDevice
var deviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
var dataOutput: AVCaptureStillImageOutput?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}

@IBAction func scan(_ sender: NSButton) {
    do {
        deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)

        cameraSession.beginConfiguration()

        if (cameraSession.canAddInput(deviceInput) == true) {
            cameraSession.addInput(deviceInput)
        }

        dataOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()

        if (cameraSession.canAddOutput(dataOutput) == true) {
            cameraSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
        }

        cameraSession.commitConfiguration()

        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: cameraSession)
        previewBox.layer?.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
        previewLayer?.frame = (previewBox.layer?.frame)!
        previewLayer?.connection.automaticallyAdjustsVideoMirroring = false
        previewLayer?.connection.isVideoMirrored = true
        cameraSession.startRunning()
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        NSLog("\(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

@IBAction func capture(_ sender: NSButton) {
    if let videoConnection = dataOutput?.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {
        dataOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: self.displayImage)
    }
}

func displayImage(buffer: CMSampleBuffer?, err: Error?) {
    let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer)
    cameraSession.stopRunning()
    captureBox.image = NSImage(data: imageData!)
}
}
```

Now... everything looks ok the preview is working, the buffer seems to have something in it - although that may be corrupted also since I can't display the image even if I comment the line with the crash (the main problem I'm asking about now). But... when it get's to the stopRunning() function the app crashes (print below). Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? If I comment the stop running part the app doesn't crash but the image is not set (that's why I pasted all... I'm expecting the problem to be somewhere else in code).

[image]

IMPORTANT: This is cocoa app, not iOS (and apparently there are 999999 code examples for iOS and 0 for macOS).